# How to install Google App Engine SDK for PHP on Ubuntu 16.04+

Tags: php, php7

I am following the [Quick Start Wordpress for Google App Engine](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/appengine-php-wordpress-starter-project/) instructions and I'd like to download and install Google App Engine SDK for PHP. I tried to follow the instructions on https://cloud.google.com/appengine/downloads#Google_App_Engine_SDK_for_PHP, which include installing `php5-cgi`

`$ sudo apt-get install php5-cgi`

Unfortunately php5-cgi doesn't seem to be available as i get the following error.

`E: Package 'php5-cgi' has no installation candidate`

Is it ok to just use php7-cgi or does Google App Engine SDK for PHP use any PHP syntax which has since been removed? 
If Google App Engine SDK for PHP does require php5-cgi then how can i install it and does this mean i can't use php7 on my system.

Comment: While this is an **excellent** question, I'm afraid it isn't a good fit for AskUbuntu. AU is not a forum, but rather a Q&A site, and so opinion based questions are considered off-topic.

Comment: You might be able to salvage the question by asking for objective assessments instead of opinions, i. e. the advantages and disadvantages of one option compared to the other.

Comment: OP if you are trying to edit your post, please log in rather than suggesting an edit as another user.

Comment: @kurt-peek 
"The preferred tooling for managing your App Engine applications in PHP is now the [Google Cloud SDK](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/). " [src](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/php/download) The original php sdk is very old.